# KSH shell script won't execute and returns 127 (not found)

Tags: ksh, execution, return-code

Can anyone enlighten me why the following won't work?

```
$ groups
  staff btgroup
$ ls -l
  total 64
  -rw-rw----    1 sld248   btgroup       26840 Apr 02 13:39 padaddwip.jks
  -rwxrwx---    1 sld248   btgroup        1324 Apr 02 13:39 padaddwip.ksh
$ ./padaddwip.ksh
  ksh: ./padaddwip.ksh:  not found.
$ echo $?
  127
```

This is nearly identical to another script which works just fine.  I can't see any differences between the two in terms of permissions or ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be 2 problems:

- Shebang line is wrong (as ghostdog alluded to)
- The script was saved from Windows and has DOS line endings.

For the latter, do

```
head padaddwip.ksh | cat -vet | head -1
```

The command should produce the shebang line NOT ending with `^M`. If it does end with `^M` that's a DOS-encoded file, and the fix is:

```
cp padaddwip.ksh padaddwip.ksh.bak
dos2unix padaddwip.ksh.bak > padaddwip.ksh
./padaddwip.ksh
```

On systems without dos2unix, you can use

```
cat padaddwip.ksh.bak | tr -d "\r" > padaddwip.ksh
```

Comment: OK, thanks DVK, I think you're right.  My other script which works does not have the ^M at the end of each line, but the script which doesn't work does have the ^M at the end of each line.  Unfortunately, dos2unix isn't installed on my AIX server (and I don't have root priviledges).  I shall pester the powers that be.  Is there a way to FTP a file to an AIX server which would strip/convert correctly?

Comment: @Chris - Yes. Set "ascii" mode in FTP

Comment: @Chris - also, in the abscence of dos2unix, just run `cat padaddwip.ksh.bak | tr -d "\r" > padaddwip.ksh`

Answer (score 1):

just a guess, check your shebang in `padaddwip.ksh`. it should be something like `#!/bin/ksh`. If not, use `which ksh` to see where your `ksh` is installed. Alternatively, you can execute your script by calling the interpreter(ksh) eg

`$ /bin/ksh padaddwip.ksh`

another way you can do is changing your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env ksh`

Also, make sure the user executing the script has its primary group as `btgroup`

Comment: First line of script shows: #!/bin/ksh

And 'which ksh' shows: /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: then why don't you try changing your shebang to that of `/usr/bin/ksh` and see.

Comment: Thanks ghostdog74, I think your recommendation will work.  Interestingly, the output of /bin/ksh padaddwip.ksh is:

    $ /bin/ksh padaddwip.ksh
    padaddwip.ksh[13]: ^M:  not found.
    padaddwip.ksh[14]: ^M:  not found.
    padaddwip.ksh[17]: ^M:  not found.
    Logging all output to padaddwip.log
    ....

Is it these ^M characters which are causing the issue?

Comment: ah, then you should remove those `^M` using tools like `dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to rid your scripts of the annoying `^M` characters would be to open the file in vi and type `:%s/^M//g` (sed within vi) where the `^M` here is created by typing `Ctrl-V` then `Ctrl-M`. I personally like this method because you don't need to create a backup file and you instantly see the results -just an OCD habit of mine-

Also, I have had some weird problems with using `tr` and control characters such as `\r` it may have been a shell or site-specific issue, but in such cases I needed to use either the above method or sed from the command line...very to similar what DVK shows above; like `sed -e 's/^M//g' padaddwip.ksh.bak > padaddwip.ksh` where you create the `^M` by doing `Ctrl-V` then `Ctrl-M` (when in vi editor mode).

Comment: I'll admit to not knowing VI at all, but thanks for the useful response.

Answer (score 0):

the shebang is bad.

test the scenario with the shell interpreter on the cmdline.

```
ksh padaddwip.ksh
```